# Execution failed for task ':expo:compileReleaseKotlin'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo, eas

I am building a react native app using eas. Its failing each time i try and i have no idea what could be the issue. `this is the error its showing

```
Task :expo:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED1470
[stderr] e: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt: (50, 3): 'getUIImplementationProvider' overrides nothing1471
[stderr] e: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt: (50, 76): Unresolved reference: UIImplementationProvider1472
[stderr] e: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt: (51, 12): Not enough information to infer type variable T1473> 
Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[x86_64]1474w: 
Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions1475Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.1476You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.1477See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings1478Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.1479Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.1480377 actionable tasks: 377 executed1481
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.1482
[stderr] * What went wrong:1483[stderr] Execution failed for task ':expo:compileReleaseKotlin'.1484[stderr] > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction1485[stderr]    > Compilation error. See log for more details1486
[stderr] * Try:1487[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.1488[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.1489[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.1490[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org1491[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 5m 47s1492Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

i have tried un installing and reinstalling expo cli on machine which is using linux(Crostini to be precise) because some of the errors it was highlighting were deprecation errors of some of the installed modules. ive tried building it a number of times, revisiting my code and searching online hoping that i may i be able to pin point where its going wrong

Comment: [Try this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210). It is a general problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is to upgrade your react native package to the  patch version as described here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

[image]